# SSH Tunnel can't connect through existing tunnel -- chanel3: open failed: administratively prohibited

Tags: ssh, tunnel, sshd

I am following [this tutorial](http://juliansimioni.com/blog/2014/02/10/howto-access-a-linux-machine-behind-a-home-router-with-ssh-tunnels/)
and I have gotten past the part where I create a tunnel from my local computer (Host B) to a remote computer (Host A) with

```
ssh -L 19922:HostA:22 HostA
```

however, when I try to check that tunnel with the command

```
ssh localhost -p 19922
```

I get the following error messages:
On Host B

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

On Host A

```
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

I following reccommendations I have found elsewhere I have added to host A's sshd config file:

```
GatewayPorts yes
PermitTunnel yes
AllowTCPForwarding yes
```

And in HostB

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

Both computers already have `UsePam yes` set.
I reset ssh on host A and B with

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Despite these changes I still get the same message. Any suggestions?

edit: I also tried opening ports 19922 and 22 on both the guest and the host with ufw.

```
 ufw allow 19922
```

Also following these suggestions I checked and ensured that PermitRoute isn't in either sshd_config file

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open

Also the results of using tracerroute are below

```
> sudo traceroute -T -p 19922 remote

traceroute to remote (198.105.244.24), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1 DD-WRT (192.168.1.1)  3.834 ms  4.324 ms  5.303 ms  
2  * * *  
3 dtr01rancca-tge-0-1-1-0.ranc.ca.charter.com (96.34.102.157)  17.343 ms  17.772 ms  23.826 ms
4  crr01rvsdca-tge-0-0-0-4.rvsd.ca.charter.com (96.34.100.248)  26.357 ms crr01rvsdca-tge-0-4-0-4.rvsd.ca.charter.com (96.34.100.208)  31.180 ms crr01rvsdca-tge-0-6-0-5.rvsd.ca.charter.com (96.34.99.236)  29.381 ms  
5  bbr01rvsdca-bue-2.rvsd.ca.charter.com (96.34.2.66)  29.737 ms  30.268 ms  30.948 ms  
6  prr01lsanca-bue-5.lsan.ca.charter.com (96.34.3.7)  28.113 ms  17.451 ms  17.614 ms  
7  v104.core1.lax1.he.net (64.71.191.253)  16.200 ms  16.083 ms  17.612 ms  
8  10ge10-8.core1.nyc4.he.net (72.52.92.225)  86.205 ms  99.092 ms  97.009 ms  
9  xerocole-inc.10gigabitethernet12-4.core1.nyc4.he.net (216.66.41.242) 89.484 ms  89.466 ms  89.337 ms 
10  * * * 
11  * * * 
12  * * * 
13  * * * 
14  * * * 
15  * * * 
16  * * * 
17  * * * 
18  * * * 
19  * * * 
20  * * * 
21  * * * 
22  * * * 
23  * * * 
24  * * * 
25  * * * 
26  * * * 
27  * * * 
28  * * * 
29  * * * 
30  * * *
```